# IE fails to show html background image (colour is ok)

Tags: html, css

So Chrome and FF are ok, just IE9 fails to show html background - it shows its colour, but no image. How I can make it to work propertly?

Test it on: [here](http://%C5%9Bwiadomesny.pl/bg/)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #ffeacd;
    background-image: url(bg.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    background-position: center top;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(bg_overlay.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.content {
    width:1020px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tested in IE9 and IE8 - the image is there. However it's HUGE and you have to wait while it gets downloaded. You have to re-save it in an optimized version for the web

Comment: doing some research on your page, it seems that if i disable the body's background image, it will show the HTML's background image, that's what i've gathered so far...

Comment: If this helps, this guy on a previous question found a workaround by changing the doctype. i can't test it on my own, but you should try it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6834087/874533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems IE is not allowing the background image tag on the html element. Try doing something like this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color: #ffeacd;
background-image: url(header-ad.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
background-position: center top;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(hdr_GSA_lp.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.content {
width:1020px;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```