# IE doesn't show my bottom background-image

Tags: css, html

I created a webpage that uses two images as a background - one for the top and one for the bottom. Chrome, Safari and Firefox display the page without issue but, in IE the background at the bottom doesn't show. Here is the code I'm using:

```
html {
  font:100%;
  background:url(../images/test8-300.jpg) repeat-x, url(../images/Html-background-Bottom2.png) no-repeat bottom;
  background-color:#d7d7d7;
}
```

If you need to have a look to understand better, this is the address: doggiestime.co.uk. At the bottom, you should be able to see some dogs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122727/internet-explorer-doesnt-recognise-the-html-css-background-image-tag

Comment: which IE version you use, it is multiple background style, where just IE10 supports

Comment: I'm using IE-9 and IE-10.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
background:#fff repeat-x no-repeat bottom;
background-image:url(../images/test8-300.jpg), url(../images/Html-background-Bottom2.png);
```

Comment: I testing on IE9 and even on my laptop running win8 which has an preview of IE10 it doesn't work.

Comment: Multiple background images aren't supported on IE versions lower than 9. Try to set the background to your body, like Keeg below suggested.

Comment: I've tried your code but it didn't solve the problem. With it, my top image is repeating vertically and the bottom background-image still not displaying at all. Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your background image to the `<body>` tag not `<html>`

```
body {
  font:100%;
  background:url(../images/test8-300.jpg) repeat-x, url(../images/Html-background-Bottom2.png) no-repeat bottom;
  background-color:#d7d7d7;
}
```